# How can I get all normalized links with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have links on my page. How can I get all links except # and javascript:void(0) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `.not()` and attribute starts with `^=` selectors to get the elements you are looking for:

```
$( "a:not( [href^='#'], [href^='javascript:void'] )");
```

This query will search for all `a` elements who's `href` attribute does not start with the hash sign (`#`) or the string `javascript:void`.

References:

- [Attribute starts with selector (`^=`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
- [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)